# adb: command not found

Tags: android

adbコマンドを使用したところ、"adb: command not found" とエラーが返ってきました。
色々と調べると環境変数を変えればいいことがわかり、下のようにパスを変更しました。

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/sdk/platform-tools
```

しかしその後adbコマンドを使用したところ、また "adb: command not found" というエラーが出てきました。確認したところ、platform-toolsフォルダの中にはadbがありました。

かれこれずっと調べているのですがこれ以上どうすればいいか分からないので、どなたかお助けいただきたいと思います。
すみませんが宜しくお願いします。

Comment: 一度ターミナルを終了した後の話ですか？ ログイン毎に `export` コマンドを実行させるようにします。 `~/.bashrc` ファイルに、`export` コマンドを書いてください。

Comment: 2点確認。 1.`export～`は実行しましたんでしょうか？どこかのファイルに書き加えましたか？ 2./Applications/sdk/platform-tools/adb ならcommand not foundになりませんか？

Comment: Hiroshi Yamamotoさんご回答ありがとうございます。
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/sdk/platform-toolsを.bash_profileに書き加えた後にadbコマンドを実行しました。ターミナルは終了させてないです。

flied onionさんご回答ありがとうございます。
すみません、1.のexport〜を実行したというのはどういうことでしょうか？export〜はbashファイルに書き込みました。2.でも試してみたところcommand not foundになってしまいました。

Comment: ターミナルで「. ~/.bash_profile」を実行してから adb を実行してみて下さい。

Comment: `export～`はコマンドです。bash_profileやbashrcに書き加えた場合は次回bash起動時に自動的に実行されますが、今開いているbashには効果がありません。即時反映させたいなら同じコマンドを実行したり、sourceコマンドで今開いているプロンプトでも実行したり、HiroshYamamotoさんが言うようにターミナルを起動し直す必要があります。

Comment: $ /Applications/sdk/platform-tools/adbを実行してもcommand not foundになるのなら、pathが違うかもしれません。ターミナルを開き直してもだめなら、場所をもう一度確認された方がいいでしょう。

Comment: ターミナルを起動し直してadbと入力すると、
「Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32」
とターミナルに表示されました！
環境変数に関することがあまりよくわかっていたので、皆様に詳しく説明していただきとても助かりました！本当にありがとうございます。

Comment: 解決されたら、その内容をまとめてご自身で回答し、正解としてチェックされると良いですよ。(後から見る方のために役立ちます)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

下記の記述をbashファイルに追加した後、ターミナルを再起動させることでadbコマンドを実行することができました。

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/sdk/platform-tools
```

Answer (score 1):

64bit 版のディストリビューションを使用していて、adb が 32bit 版ということはありませんか?
こういう場合にも command not found になります。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。bit数の違いでもcommand not foundになるのですね。ぜひ覚えておきたいと思います。